# Swift - Taking a variable set as an array out of a function

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

How can I fix this error, while still keeping the value of the array the same? Here's a screenshot of my code:[image]

Comment: It's unclear where the upper part of the code belongs to. By the way please don't post images, post text.

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var group_array` is defined out of `VStack` scope.
I suggest using `@State` in order to store `group_array`.

```
@State var group_array: Array
var body: some View {
....
```

Comment: I tried this and it gave me the error "Reference to generic type 'Array' requires arguments in <...>" and suggested inserting "<Any>" I did that and am now getting a new error on line 48: "Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type '(Any) throws -> Bool'"

Comment: Provide your full code. It seems, you should write `return HomeScreen()` instead of `HomeScreen()`. Same for `Verify()`.

Comment: I got it working. Just had to set "public var group_array: Array<String> = []" at the very top before any struct. Then, I run the function to set that variable before the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly the question, and the problem... you have to set `var group_array` as a property of the class.

This way you could access it in the Firestore function, and read it in body view.